# retain some html elements without replace new same html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxs within my li, I want the li to be editable by dlbclick, but it will remove the checbox. I can include the checkbox together with my text value, but I do not want to do so, any other way?

http://jsfiddle.net/64V4p/4/

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '#li', function () {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    input = $("<input type='text' id='input'>");
    input.appendTo($(this)).focus();

});

$(document).on('focusout', '#input', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        newInput = $(this).val();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('li').text(newInput);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('li').text(oriVal);
    }

});
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li id="li">
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">item 1</li>
    <li id="li">
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

```
<ul>
    <li class="li">
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"/><span>item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="li">
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2"/><span>item 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '.li', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $.trim($this.text());
    $this.data('text', text);
    $("<input />", {
        value: text,
            'class': 'edit'
    }).appendTo($(this).find('span').empty()).focus();
    $this.find('input[type="checkbox"]').hide();
});

$(document).on('focusout', '.edit', function () {
    var value = $.trim(this.value),
        $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $li.find('span').text(value == '' ? $li.data('text') : value)
    $li.find('input[type="checkbox"]').show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CVgMZ/)

*Since you have multiple elements with the id `li` do not use id attribute, use class instead because ID of an element must be unique in a document*

Comment: thx so much!     var value = $.trim(this.value),
why in here u used this instead of $(this)? and the comma instead of ;??

Comment: @HildyMaass since it is a input field there you can access the value from the dom reference itself there is no need to use [$(this).val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) here

Comment: @HildyMaass in order to use [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare multiple variables you can separate them using `,`

Comment: I tried to add keypress like this http://jsfiddle.net/CVgMZ/3/ but it doesn't work..

Comment: it work but this error shown in the console "An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. "

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://jsfiddle.net/64V4p/4/

Simply takte the checkbox outside the 'li'. You can then arrange the checkbox in line with your text using CSS.

```
<ul>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"><li id="li">item 1</li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2"><li id="li">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when u edited the li text, the checkbox will be gone, I just want to edit the li text without effecting the checkbox

Comment: No, look at other answer